# Blocking app from running on iOS 3.2 without blocking it on 3.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect

I'd like to release an app that runs on old iPhones - that is, that runs on 3.1 - but blocking it from running on iPad's iOS 3.2.

Game runs perfectly on iPhones with iOS 3.1.3 and newer, and on iPads with iOS 4 and newer. However, some scaling issues occur on iPads with iOS 3.2.

Is it possible to block the app from appearing as compatible with iOS 3.2 on iTunes Store and to block if from installation on iOS 3.2, but still make it run on iOS 3.1.3?

---

Some clarifications:

- We definitely don't want to block iPad users.
- Game fully works on iPhones and iPod Touches with iOS 3.1.3.
- Game fully works on iPads with iOS 4.
- The only combo with issues is iPad with iOS 3.2.
- Runtime solutions are not what we're looking for.

I suspect this is due to Apple's scaling code intended for retina displays accidentally making it into iOS 3.2. While I could certainly spend loads of time pinning down the issues, I don't feel like it. iOS 3.2 has a small user base, and iPad users have no reason to avoid upgrading. At the same time, we're trying not to cut off iPhone 2G, iPhone 3G, iPod Touch 1G and iPod Touch 2G  users who cannot upgrade or don't want to upgrade due to slowdowns.

Also, telling users that they just bought an app that won't work on their device would result in bad user experience. Blocking off a specific version of OS from installation via the App Store would be ideal, without blocking all lesser versions, too.

Comment: As soon as somebody updates their OS, it will break your app. Apple will remove an app from the store if it does this. The correct solution is to fix your app.

Comment: Sounds like a cop out to me. How difficult is it to correct the scaling issues you're having on ipad? My opinion is either build for iOS >3.2 and exclude old iphone software or if it matters so much then correct the problems you're having with the iPad.

Comment: I don't think Apple would approve any software that explicitly excluded iPad. Don't do this--as the above posters said, you should fix your app.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: 3.2 is the original iPad operating system, noone upgrades to it. All works on 4+.

Comment: @ThomasClayson: It's rather difficult since it seems to be an Apple bug that manifests only on 3.2. Game is a mix of IB and non-IB code and hacks. Only 3.2 causes issues, and we don't want to drop people who CANNOT upgrade such as owners of 1G devices, or who don't want to slow down their devices such as owners of 2G devices. iPad users with iOS 3.2 are capable of upgrading, why don't they?

Comment: @nielsbot: Once again, we in the team are not avoiding iPad users and are fully aware of Apple's rules. We're simply trying to avoid cutting off 1G and 2G iPhone and iPod devices, and at the same time prevent people mistakenly purchasing the game on iPad with iOS 3.2 and then being surprised about poor experience.  Everything works on iOS 4+!

Comment: I'm well aware that iPad shipped with iOS 3.2. It's irrelevant however. You must not block individual OS versions--it will make Apple very angry. If it's really that bad, show an alert that says "Please update to the latest version of iOS for best experience" but allow the user to continue using 3.2 if they choose to.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Point of the question is precisely to find out if there is a legal way to block the app from being installable :-) I'm not trying to block the users from launching the game once they obtained and installed it (as I clarified in the last paragraph of the updated question).

Comment: No, there is no way to do it while maintaining compatibility with 3.1.3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Technically you can do that. **It's not recommendation to do such!**
E.g. in applicationDidFinishLaunching you could do:

```
if ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] rangeOfString:@"iPad"] != NSNotFound && [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]==3.2) 
    exit(0);
```

There high enough chances Apple will approve that app. Not because they will be happy with your solution but because they will not test your app on iPad with iOS 3.2.

You have no way to allow running app on 3.1 and higher except iPad 3.2. **The only legal way I see to prevent your app from being installed on 3.2 - set 3.2.1 as deployment target of your app.** If you cannot guarantee your app will work on all devices, move deployment target higher.

Comment: Great, so the iPad owner with iOS 3.2 buys the app and it "crashes" on launch. That'll surely help with getting favorable reviews...

Comment: @omz, I am clearly stating that it's possible technically, but that is not preferred way.

Comment: This is terrible. People with ipads 3.2 will download the app and then just not be able to open it.

Comment: Removed my downvote. Technically you're answering the question. Just DON'T DO THIS unless you want to fall out with your users and apple.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson, yepp. That's why I recommend move deployment target to 3.2.1.

Comment: Your code doesn't even work as intended; you're blocking every iPad, not just those with iOS 3.2. Also, it doesn't really answer the original question, which was whether it's possible to make the app appear as incompatible with 3.2 _in the store_, so nobody with 3.2 could actually download it (which is btw impossible).

Comment: @omz, oh, you are right about the code, now it's ok. Copy/paste, you know. About the rest you are not right. I DID reply the answer: "The only legal way I see - set 3.2.1 as deployment target of your app." Anyway, I agree with your downvote with resignation, my older comrad)

Comment: This is DEFINITELY not what we want to do. That's even worse than current experience on iOS 3.2. We are trying to prevent users from PURCHASING and INSTALLING the game on 3.2, while not blocking off 3.1.3 users.

Comment: +1 Question answered, regardless of the **opinions** of other voters/commentators.  I find it funny when people downvote, but provide no solution of their own...  I can hear it now... _"I dont know how to do it, but dont do it that way!"_

Comment: @chown, thanks. Your comment is a balm for me after those downvotes)

Comment: I'll be accepting this answer only because of the last paragraph, and only if noone comes along with a better solution.  I'm not downvoting it. I'm rather disappointed that I didn't miss Apple's documentation on how to do this, and that you truly cannot blacklist particular versions of the OS.

Comment: @chown... You are completely wrong. Just because I don't have an answer doesn't mean that I don't know that this answer is wrong, or can't comment on its pitfalls. "I don't know how to do it, but don't do it that way!" is a perfectly good response to an answer like this.